# How to send the position on a board from a Board to a Cell component in React JS using nested array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am making a gameboard in React JS represented by a 2D array. A Board component uses an array.map function to loop through the rows and a nested array.map function for the columns again to render Cell components to form a table.

I can't figure out how to send the position on the board/array to the Cell component. I would like to make 2-elements array in every nested loop with the row number and column number and send that as a props to the cell.

But how can I access the index of the outer map function?

Here are my Board and Cell components:

```
var Board = React.createClass({
  //dungeon map available in this.props.board  

  render: function() {

    return (

      <table className="table">
        {
          this.props.board.map(function(item,index){
          //loop through every element of the board array
          //these are the rows

          var row = index;

            return (

              <tr>
                {

                  item.map(function(item,index){

                    var position = [row, index]
                    //this does not work for row
                   //row from outer map loop not accessible

                    return (

                      <Cell value={item} position ={position}/>

                    )

                  }.bind(this))


                }

              </tr>  


            )


          }.bind(this))

        } 
      </table>

    )

  }

});

var Cell = React.createClass({
//this.props.position available here

    return (

      <td>
        {this.props.item}
      </td>

    )

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it in the binding:

```
var Board = React.createClass({
//dungeon map available in this.props.board  

render: function() {

    return (

    <table className="table">
        {
        this.props.board.map(function(item,index){
        //loop through every element of the board array
        //these are the rows

        var row = index;

            return (

            <tr>
                {

                /** NOTICE rowIndex **/  
                item.map(function(rowIndex, item,index){

                    var position = [row, index]
                    //this does not work for row
                //row from outer map loop not accessible

                    return (

                    <Cell value={item} position ={rowIndex}/>

                    )

                /** NOTICE we pass the row's index to binding **/
                }.bind(this, index))


                }

            </tr>  


            )


        }.bind(this))

        } 
    </table>

    )

}

});
```

*NOTE:* The order matters. notice `rowIndex` is first.